# Compound discount

Tags: economics

I am trying to construct an equation for calculating a price, that takes into account compound interest of 10%.

```
1 item  = $10
2 items = $19
3 items = $27.1
```

so for a given number of items, I can calculate the price.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying that the first item costs $10$, the second $10*0.9$, the third $10*0.9^2$.  The total is then a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):  $10(1+0.9+0.9^2+\ldots 0.9^n)$ which sums to $10\left(\frac {1-0.9^{n}}{1-0.9}\right)$

Comment: That's great! thanks very much Ross. Would it be difficult to adjust that equation so that the first term was $10 the second was ((10*0.8) * 0.9), the third ((10*0.8)*0.9^2). Essentially the base price is reduced by 20% for all terms but the first.

Comment: @pingu:  Then consider the first item special.  You just change the factor $10$ to $8$, but add 2 to fix the price of the first one.

Comment: and an infinite number costs a total of $100

Comment: @Henry:  Good point.  I'll take 'em.  How much is the shipping?

Comment: @Henry - That is actually what I wanted, the items in question are actually web service accounts, and I want the price to tend towards an upper limit.

Comment: @Ross - Not convinced the above equation is correct, when you have 1 item, it calculates the price as $19

Comment: @pingu: sorry-off by one in the exponent

Comment: @Ross - If I try and correct it by changing the exponent from (n+1) to just (n) then i cant get it to work with my additional question of the first term being a special case.

Comment: @Ross - I have an additional problem. If I change the exponent to (n-1) so that the equation above evaluates to 0 for n=1, so that I am able to add the first term as a special case, then when n=2 the second item has no compound discount applied.

Comment: I have added my follow up question as a new question here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/377624/geometric-series-to-calculate-price

Comment: @pingu:  The exponent was $n+1$.  I have changed it to $n$ which works perfectly.